# Retrieving data from two tables with sql

Tags: sql

I am not sure what I want to do is possible, but ...

I have two tables that will be joined on a name field.  Each table will have the same respective fields however, the values may or may not be the same.  I would like a query that would pull only the rows where the respective field values are different.  I know I could do that with a long clause containing ORs and NOT EQUALs, but if for example, the table contained 15 fields, then this would not be fun.  Can you programmatically enumerate any number of fields and compare those fields for differences in values?

Comment: The keyword here is `JOIN`. For quick help, it would be useful if you can post the table and your efforts to get what you want. That's the SO way.

Comment: Is there a key field that has same values in both these tables?

Comment: Is your intention to join two tables given a single identifying column and compare the other column values without specifying the names of the other columns? i.e. the script would interrogate the table schema

Answer (score 0):

Maybe MINUS would work?

```
SELECT name, dob, gender FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT name, dob, gender FROM table2;
```